# linux command to prevent dos attack by using netstat and iptables

Tags: networking, security, iptables, command-line-interface

I want to DROP more than 200 requests per ip to prevent ddos attack. this is command that i used to detect requests count per ip :

```
netstat -alpn | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' |awk -F: '{print $(NF-1)}' |sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

now i want add all ip addresses that made more than 200 requests into IPtables to DROP input and out put.

Comment: As @dawud mentioned make sure you are aware that you can only "mitigate" and not really totally prevent DDOS attack to your server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use iptables to limit the rate of incoming connections. For example if you don't want more than 200 connections per minute from a source:

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set`

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 200 -j DROP`

Comment: It would be great to have an explanation of this as well.

Answer (score 18):

You can create an `ipset`. This way you can add as many IPs to the set as you need without modifying the `iptables` ruleset.

```
ipset -N myset iphash
ipset -A myset 1.1.1.1
ipset -A myset 2.2.2.2
```

Or, in your case, use the output of your script, and read it with something like:

```
while read a; do ipset -A myset "$a"; done < <(your script here)
```

And the reference it in your `iptables` rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --set myset src -j DROP
```

Read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipset) for more details and options.

There are also other ways to **mitigate** a DDOS attack using `iptables` directly. Read the `iptables` manpage section about the `connlimit` and `recent` modules.

Comment: This is brilliant because ipsets are much faster than alternatives such as hashtables.